# Can not import mongo object in other file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, flask-pymongo

Using flask-restful, i can not import the object `mongo = PyMongo()` from the file `app/__init__.py` into `app/common/db.py`.

My ***folder structure*** looks like this:

```
myproject/
   run.py
   app/
      __init__.py
      config.py
      common/
         __init__.py
         db.py
      auth/
         __init__.py
         resources.py
```

***app/__init__.py*** contains:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_restful import Api
from app.config import Config

from app.auth.resources import Foo

mongo = PyMongo()

bp_auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)
api_auth = Api(bp_auth)

api_auth.add_resource(Foo, '/foo/<string:name>')

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    mongo.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(bp_auth)

    return app
```

***app/common/db.py*** contains:

```
from app import mongo
```

the application itself is run from the root via ***run.py*** which contains:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Problem:**

Running the application i get an ImportError:

> from app import mongo
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'mongo'

Why this is not working?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Full Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/home/bt/Dropbox/dev/flask/test_api/app/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from app.auth.resources import SignIn, Users, User, Foo
  File "/home/bt/Dropbox/dev/flask/test_api/app/auth/resources.py", line 8, in <module>
    from app.common.resources import AuthResource
  File "/home/bt/Dropbox/dev/flask/test_api/app/common/resources.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.auth.decorators import token_required
  File "/home/bt/Dropbox/dev/flask/test_api/app/auth/decorators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app.common.database import users
  File "/home/bt/Dropbox/dev/flask/test_api/app/common/database.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import mongo
ImportError: cannot import name 'mongo'
```

Comment: What's in auth folder? This seems like a circular import. Can you copy the full traceback?

Comment: Of course, added traceback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected, this is a **circular import** problem.

You can track the closed loop of dependencies looking at the traceback:

```
app -> resources -> database -> app
```

This is a common mistake and not properly documented in Flask tutorials. As explained [here by Lepture](https://lepture.com/en/2018/structure-of-a-flask-project), you should avoid declaring db in the `__init__.py`

> I always keep this one certain rule when writing modules and packages:
>
> **Don't backward import from root `__init__.py`.**

How should you do it, then?

- declare db in the proper module (`db.py`)
- import it **inside** the application factory

I found myself reluctant towards this pattern, I thought those `import` statements didn't belong inside a function. But this is the way to go.

So, your files should look something alike:

**app/common/db.py**

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
...

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    from app.common.db import mongo
    mongo.init_app(app)
    ...
```

and when you need your database connection, i.e. in resources module, you should import it like

```
from app.common.db import mongo
```

Note: to avoid future problems, your blueprints should also be declared elsewhere and import on creation time. I really encourage you to read the [post by Lepture](https://lepture.com/en/2018/structure-of-a-flask-project) to better understand this approach.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me a lot :)

Comment: I tried to follow this but it is not working for me. @Susensio could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568304/flask-pymongo-init-app-missing-1-required-positional-argument-app