# Flask-PyMongo - init_app() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, flask-restful, flask-pymongo

i am trying to initialise my db using flask-pymongo.

But i get the following error,

> File "run.py", line 22, in 
>   app = create_app("config")
>   File "run.py", line 11, in create_app
>   mongo.init_app(app)
>   TypeError: init_app() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'

**run.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from app import api_bp
from db import mongo

def create_app(config_filename):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_filename)
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

    mongo.init_app(app)

    return app

# def logger():


# def database():


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app("config")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

**db.py**

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

mongo = PyMongo
```

**config.py**

```
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = "secret"
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/api"
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
import os
import json
import datetime
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import jsonify
from flask_restful import Api
from .users.resource import UsersResource

api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)


api.add_resource(UsersResource, '/users')
```

**app/users/resource.py**

I want to them import the mongo to this resource so i can access the users collection.

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import jsonify
from .repository import UsersRepository

class UsersResource(Resource):

    def __init__(self):

        self.repository = UsersRepository()

    def get(self):

        data = {"Users": "Resource"}
        res = data, 200
        return res
```

I am trying to setup a restful api with resources using Flask-restful and flask-pymongo. Any other suggestions to improve my approach is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't instantiate the PyMongo class in db.py.

```
mongo = PyMongo()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use flask-pymongo like [this](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase"
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

So in run.py, you should use this code:

```
from flask import Flask
from app import api_bp
from db import mongo

def create_app(config_filename):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_filename)
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

    # mongo.init_app(app) # remove this line

    return app

# def logger():


# def database():


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app("config")
    py_mongo = mongo(app)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```